# How do I fixed this notice for all position:fixed;

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a notice as in the pictures

But some extensions will appear above this notification

this css for notice

```
display: block;
position:fixed;
```

for "online" css

```
display:inline-block;
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You really need some clarification here. I have absolutely no clue what you're looking for?

Comment: Can you add some sample html and css so we can duplicate the issue and help you?

Answer (score 0):

It could be those other elements also have `position:fixed` on them. One solution is to use `z-index` and set it higher than the other element

As you haven't supplied any sample html/css for us to duplicate this issue, I'm going to use some generic HTML:

```css
div:first-of-type {
  background: red;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

.fixed.green {
  background: green;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>Some content</div>
<div class="fixed green">Fixed element</div>
<div class="fixed">Another fixed element</div>
```

As you can see, the green div is under the blue one. This will represent your notification.

By adding `z-index:5;` to the green div (in this example any value greater than 1 will work) the green div will appear at a higher level than the blue div and become visible:

```css
div:first-of-type {
  background: red;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

.fixed.green {
  background: green;
  z-index: 5;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>Some content</div>
<div class="fixed green">Fixed element</div>
<div class="fixed">Another fixed element</div>
```

The maximum value for z-index varies by browser but generally is in the millions. Feel free to set the notification z-index to 9999 or some other super-high value.